# fetch-blob-react-native "Error: can't open file"

Tags: react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

when I go for the code here .. http://www.rntools.co/pkg/react-native-fetch-blob
I installed library successfully and download file but when I try top open that (PDF) file .. android emulator say (Can't open file) ..